# Sorting in finder giving unexpected results when using numbers and letters

Tags: finder

I have a folder with the following files, and when the setting is to sort by name I would expect them to be in the following order:

```
01-a.txt
01-b.txt
01-c.txt
02-a.txt
02-b.txt
...
09-b.txt
09-c.txt
0A-a.txt
0A-b.txt
Etc
```

However, what I get is

```
0A-a.txt
0A-b.txt
01-a.txt
01-b.txt
Etc
```

If I leave of the leading zeros it sorts as expected.

What is the reason for this, and is there a way to make it work as expected?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right. And I guess there isn't a way to switch from "natural" sort order to alphabetical sort order.

Comment: Right, MacOS has behaved this way for about 20 years now.